# Run Time 1004: Application Defined Error at Refresh Background Query

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that runs perfectly fine on my machine. But for some reason, it keeps throwing application defined error on my colleague's machine. I've checked VPN, ODBC connection and all other trivial things but I keep getting the error.

```
  ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="campaign", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Odbc.DataSource(""dsn=Vertica"", [HierarchicalNavigation=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    pvcdw_Database = Source{[Name=""pvxdw"",Kind=""Database""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Campaign_Schema = pvcdw_Database{[Name=""Campaign"",Kind=""Schema""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    campaign_Table = Campaign_Schema{[Name=""campaign"",Kind=""Table""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered" & _
        " Rows"" = Table.SelectRows(campaignbygeo_Table, each [CampaignID]=" & CID & " )," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"" = Table.RemoveColumns(#""Filtered Rows"",{""XYZPublished"", ""ABCPublished""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Columns"""
   
   
    
    
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""campaign"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$" & r & "")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
       
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [campaign]")
        
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

The above code is used to connect to Vertica via Excel Power Query and dump data onto my workbook.

I keep getting the run-time 1004 application-defined or object-defined error at this particular line:

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

I don't know what to do! This runs extremely well on my machine but no luck on my colleagues' machine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Firewall issue?

Comment: No, that can't be. They have equal access as me.